# Laravel 5 + AngularJS Cross Domain CORS

Tags: angularjs, cors, laravel-5

I have searched everywhere for an answer but nothing have worked so far. All the listed solutions on stack have not proven to be sufficient.

I get nothing in my laravel log in form of errors and I only get the standard:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.domain.dev/post/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://domain.dev' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Laravel controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Post;
use App\Tag;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostController extends Controller {

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

        $posts = Post::with('user', 'tags')->get();

        return response()->json($posts);
    }
}
```

Laravel Routes:

```
<?php

Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
Route::resource('post', 'PostController');
Route::get('post/tag/{tag}', 'PostController@postsWithTag');
Route::resource('tag', 'TagController');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

Kind of bloated not organized angular:

```
//App
var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngAnimate'
    ]);

//Config
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$animateProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $animateProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
        controller: 'PageController'
    }).
    when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutController'
    }).
    when('/contact', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html',
        controller: 'ContactController'
    }).
    when('/blog', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/blog.html',
        controller: 'PostsController'
    }).
    when('/blog/post/:postId', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/post.html',
        controller: 'PostController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });


}]);

//Factory
app.factory('Data', function Data($http) {

    return {
        getPosts: function getPosts() { return $http.get('http://api.domain.dev/post/'); },
        getPost: function getPost(id) { return $http.get('http://api.domain.dev/post/' + id); },
        addPost: function addPost(data) { return $http.post('http://api.domain.dev/post/', data); },
        removePost: function removePost(id) { return $http.delete('http://api.domain.dev/post/'+ id); },

        getTags: function getTags() { return $http.get('http://api.domain.dev/tag/'); },
        getTag: function getTag(id) { return $http.get('http://api.domain.dev/tag/' + id); },
        addTag: function addTag(data) { return $http.post('http://api.domain.dev/tag/', data); },
        removeTag: function removeTag(id) { return $http.delete('http://api.domain.dev/tag/'+ id); },

    } 
}); 

//Posts Controller
app.controller('PostsController', function PostsController($scope, Data) {



    Data.getPosts().success(parsePosts);

    function parsePosts(data) { 
        $scope.posts = data; 
    }

    //AddPost
    $scope.newPost = { title: '', content: '', resume: '' };

    $scope.addPost = function addPost(){Data.addPost({ title: $scope.newPost.title, content: $scope.newPost.content, resume: $scope.newPost.resume, user_id: $scope.newPost.user_id }).success(postAddSuccess).error(postAddError);}

    function postAddSuccess(data) {
        $scope.error = null;
        $scope.posts.push(data);
        $scope.newPost = { title: '', content: '', resume: '' }; 
    }

    function postAddError(data) { 
        $scope.error = data; 
    }

    //RemovePost
    $scope.removePost = function removePost(id) {
        if (confirm('Do you really want to remove this post?')) {
            Data.removePost(id).success(postRemoveSuccess); 
        } 
    }

    function postRemoveSuccess(data) {
        var i = $scope.posts.length;
        while (i--) {
            if ($scope.posts[i].id == data) {
                $scope.post.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }

});

//Post Controller
app.controller('PostController', function PostController($scope, $routeParams, Data) {
    Data.getPost($routeParams.id).success(parsePost);

    function parsePost(data) {
        $scope.post = data;
    }

    Data.getTags($routeParams.id).success(parsePostsTags);

    function parsePostsTags(data) {
        $scope.tags = data;
    }

    $scope.newTag = { tag: '' };

    $scope.addTag = function addTag() {
        $scope.newTag.post_id = $scope.post.id;
        Data.addTag($scope.newTag).success(tagAddSuccess).error(tagAddError);
    }

    function tagAddSuccess(data) {
        $scope.error = null;
        $scope.tags.push(data);

        $scope.newTag = { tag: '' };
    }

    function tagAddError(data) {
        $scope.error = data;
    }

    $scope.removeTag = function removeTag(id) {
        if (confirm('Do you really want to remove this tag?')) {
            Data.removeTag(id).success(tagRemoveSuccess);
        }
    }

    function tagRemoveSuccess(data) {
        var i = $scope.tags.length;
        while (i--) {
            if ($scope.tags[i].id == data) {
                $scope.tags.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
});

//About Controller
app.controller('AboutController', function AboutController($scope, Data) {



});

//Portfolio Controller
app.controller('PortfolioController', function PortfolioController($scope, Data) {



});

//Contact Controller
app.controller('ContactController', function ContactController($scope, Data) {



});

//Page Controller
app.controller('PageController', function PageController($scope, Data) {



});
```

I have no clue where to go from here. 
I have tried everything from the normal `header()` implementation to using laravel-cors package to implement via filters and the _construct in the controller. 
I have also gone the server config route and tried adding the header to the .htaccess and the virtualhost config.

Comment: Have you try [laravel-cors](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) package to send Cross-Origin Resource Sharing headers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem, but with jQuery and took me weeks to get a good solution.

I my case create an middleware to set headers was the perfect solution.

Create a Cors middleware: App\Http\Middleware\Cors.php

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors
{

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param  \Closure $next
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])
            // Depending of your application you can't use '*'
            // Some security CORS concerns 
            //->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, OPTIONS')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true')
            ->header('Access-Control-Max-Age', '10000')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
    }
}
```

Remember to set Cors alias inside App\Http\Kernel

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\Cors::class,
];
```

Inside Routes you can use middleware with group or direct to an specific route, in e.g.:

```
Route::match(['post', 'options'], 'api/...', 'Api\XController@method')->middleware('cors');
```

If someone have this problem with jQuery, I recommend to use $.ajax, instead of $.get, $.post. When you use this methods, jQuery send data using XMLHttpRequest and set content-type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, it's impossible to change that, so, use Ajax.

e.g.:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'www.foo.bar/api',
            contentType: "application/json",
            xhrFields: {
                // The 'xhrFields' property sets additional fields on the XMLHttpRequest.
                // This can be used to set the 'withCredentials' property.
                // Set the value to 'true' if you'd like to pass cookies to the server.
                // If this is enabled, your server must respond with the header
                // 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'.
                withCredentials: true

            },

            headers: {
                // Set any custom headers here.
                // If you set any non-simple headers, your server must include these
                // headers in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' response header.
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },



            data: '{"some":"json data"}',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('AJAX version');
                console.log("Works!")
            },
        });
```

Remember: If you are using application/json on request header you must provide "OPTIONS" method, to do a preflight.

More info about CORS: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: Just one more thing. If in your controller you return a new Response, `Resnpose::json()`, `Response::make()`, etc. you need to set headers again (third argument), because headers set by middleware don't pass to new Response instance.

Comment: in my case when I changed  withCredentials: true to false its works

Answer (score 4):

Add this line before return `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

Your code should be

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::with('user', 'tags')->get();
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    return response()->json($posts);
}
```

Comment: I see what you are getting at but does nothing but return the same error in chrome console.

Comment: @user2298680 I had same problem. But I solved the problem by header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");... Lets see someone will solve your problem.

Comment: My Laravel 5.0 API is losing session when angular.js apps make login from other domain. These angular.js apps are hosted in other domains, other servers.

Answer (score 2):

Add these lines in your **public/index.php**:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token'); // allow certain headers
```

See, if that works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have good knowledge in laravel.but My suggestion is to the request headers to access REST Methods(GET,POST,PUT,DELTE) and origin to specific domain from which domain your making request in the following way or else set to '*'(it allows any domain)

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'some url');
header('Allow', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
```

At angular js.If you use <1.2 you can set CORS in controller file like following way.In latest version not required it will set default.you need to set what content type your expecting from server default is json.If your expecting other type of content you can set manually in the request.

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
            delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke a cross origin XHR request, javascript first fires an OPTIONS request to the given URL. If this method hasnt added in your routes, then it pops a 404 page which is served without the ACAO header so the concrete POST request wont be sent, as javascript see it not allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?>
```

to public/index.php if it doesn't work in the function like blue bells suggested

Answer (score 0):

what i have done but not sure if that is the best solution but there are no cors with that one

1.build the angular normally using `ng build --prod`

2.move the content of `angular/dist` to `laravel/public`

3.then use this simple code in `laravel/routes/web.php`

```
Route::prefix('api')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
    });
});
Route::get('/{params?}', function () {
//    return view('welcome');
    include_once '../public/index.html';
})->where('params', '(.*)');
```

now all requests comes to Laravel and if it can catch the request with a route this route will work otherwise it will pass it to angular