# Http failure response for (unknown url) Angular 4

Tags: javascript, php, angular, laravel, rest

I am having two servers ON on system. One port serving Angular project and another one Laravel. I am using backend made in Laravel to give response in json format. I have made Angular project in which I have implemented an service to consume data from the port and display the list. As I can see in the network tab of developer tools in browser, Angular is retrieving the text from the backend server but however the list is not being displayed. It just shows that error. Here is the code

**blog-list.component.html**

```
<div>
<mat-list role="list">
<mat-list-item role="listitem" *ngFor="let blog of blogs">{{blog.id}}</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
</div>
```

**blog-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NetworkOperationsService} from '../network-operations.service';
import {Blog} from '../blog';
import {Category} from '../category';

@Component({
selector: 'app-blog-list',
templateUrl: './blog-list.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./blog-list.component.css']
})
export class BlogListComponent implements OnInit
{
blogs : Blog[];
constructor(private networkOperationsService : NetworkOperationsService)
{}
ngOnInit()
{
this.getBlogs();
}
getBlogs() : void
  {
  this.networkOperationsService.getBlogs()
  .subscribe(blogs=>this.blogs = blogs);
  }
}
```

**network-operations.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Blog} from './blog';
import {Category} from './category';
import {ApiConfigurations} from './api-configurations';


@Injectable()
export class NetworkOperationsService
{
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

 getBlogs() : Observable<Blog[]>
  {
  return this.http.get<Blog[]>('http://localhost:8000/api/blogs');
  }
}
```

**JSON Response**

```
[{"id":1,"title":"My Second Blog","body":"Here is the body of my first blogger app","categories":"[1]","created_at":"2017-12-22 11:28:02","updated_at":"2017-12-22 11:32:15"},{"id":2,"title":"Is Android a right choice for career","body":"A lot of people are trying to make android as their primary motive of their lives so please people stop there and watch for more choices and make your choices more sophesticatedly.","categories":"[1]","created_at":"2017-12-22 17:12:26","updated_at":"2017-12-22 17:12:26"},{"id":3,"title":"Is Android a right choice for career","body":"A lot of people are trying to make android as their primary motive of their lives so please people stop there and watch for more choices and make your choices more sophesticatedly.","categories":"[]","created_at":"2017-12-22 17:12:40","updated_at":"2017-12-22 17:12:40"},{"id":4,"title":"Is Android a right choice for career","body":"A lot of people are trying to make android as their primary motive of their lives so please people stop there and watch for more choices and make your choices more sophesticatedly.","categories":"[5]","created_at":"2017-12-22 17:12:45","updated_at":"2017-12-22 17:12:45"},{"id":5,"title":"Is Android a right choice for career","body":"A lot of people are trying to make android as their primary motive of their lives so please people stop there and watch for more choices and make your choices more sophesticatedly.","categories":"[6]","created_at":"2017-12-22 17:12:51","updated_at":"2017-12-22 17:12:51"},{"id":6,"title":"Is Android a right choice for career","body":"A lot of people are trying to make android as their primary motive of their lives so please people stop there and watch for more choices and make your choices more sophesticatedly.","categories":"[8]","created_at":"2017-12-22 17:12:55","updated_at":"2017-12-22 17:12:55"},{"id":7,"title":"Dushyant SUthar","body":"Dushyant SUthar","categories":"Dushyant SUthar","created_at":"2017-12-25 11:20:06","updated_at":"2017-12-25 11:20:06"}]
```

**Error Text**

```
Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
core.js:3660
ERROR 
{…}
error: error
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
explicitOriginalTarget: XMLHttpRequest { __zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "http://localhost:8000/api/blogs", readyState: 4, … }
isTrusted: true
lengthComputable: false
loaded: 0
originalTarget: XMLHttpRequest { __zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "http://localhost:8000/api/blogs", readyState: 4, … }
target: XMLHttpRequest { __zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "http://localhost:8000/api/blogs", readyState: 4, … }
timeStamp: 25351.271703
total: 0
type: "error"
__proto__: ProgressEventPrototype { lengthComputable: Getter, loaded: Getter, total: Getter, … }
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map, lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map }
message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: null
__proto__: Object { constructor: HttpErrorResponse() }
core.js:1427
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/api/blogs. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
```

Comment: post the actual error text

Comment: @bryan60 Hey I have added the error text in the update.

Comment: you have a CORS issue. your server needs to add the correct CORS header to allow cross origin requests.

Comment: @bryan60 Well I have been android developer took web things in hands first time. I don;t know CORS things or such but Will work on that to understand. Well what should I do with the question ? Should I close it or delete it.?

Comment: you can use [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) chrome extension to enable allow cross request.

Comment: @krezus could you suggest me some kind solution to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these lines on public/index.php file

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

and check this [this](http://tekina.info/cors-problem-laravel-angular/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045413/laravel-5-angularjs-cross-domain-cors)